# Log Cat Error: Device Disconnected

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to run an application on emulator and there are no errors in my program and the app loads on the emulator and suddenly stops for some reason and log cat error says `TID :-1 and Device Disconnected`. When I tried for the first time it said can't read `androidmanifest.xml` file, but when I restarted the emulator it is showing this error again and again `Device Disconnected`. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try open your `DDMS` perspective on  your Eclipse IDE, and then open the `Device` view. On the `Device` view menu, click the `Reset adb` item. Good Luck...